# How can I append a char or &str to a String without first converting it to String?

Tags: string, rust

I am attempting to write a lexer for fun, however something keeps bothering me.

```
let mut chars: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
let mut contents = String::new();
let mut tokens: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();
let mut append = String::new();
//--snip--
for _char in chars {
    append += &_char.to_string();
    append = append.trim().to_string();

    if append.contains("print") {
        println!("print found at: \n{}", append);
        append = "".to_string();
    }
}
```

Any time I want to do something as simple as append a `&str` to a `String` I have to convert it using `.to_string`, `String::from()`, `.to_owned`, etc.

Is there something I am doing wrong, so that I don't have to constantly do this, or is this the primary way of appending?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to do something with a type, check the documentation.  From the [documentation for `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html):

- [`push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push): "Appends the given `char` to the end of this `String`."
- [`push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str): "Appends a given string slice onto the end of this `String`."

Answer (score 4):

It's important to understand the differences between `String` and `&str`, and why different methods accept and return each of them.

A `&str` or `&mut str` are [usually preferred in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/493729) and return types. That's because they are just pointers to data so nothing needs to be copied or moved when they are passed around.

A `String` is returned when a function needs to do some new allocation, while `&str` and `&mut str` are slices into an existing `String`. Even though `&mut str` is mutable, you can't mutate it in a way that increases its length because that would require additional allocation.

The `trim` function is able to return a `&str` slice because that doesn't involve mutating the original string - a trimmed string is just a substring, which a slice perfectly describes. But sometimes that isn't possible; for example, a function that pads a string with an extra character would *have to* return a `String` because it would be allocating new memory.

---

You can reduce the number of type conversions in your code by choosing different methods:

```
for c in chars {
    append.push(c); // append += &_char.to_string();
    append = append.trim().to_string();

    if append.contains("print") {
        println!("print found at: \n{}", append);
        append.clear(); // append = "".to_string();
    }
}
```

There isn't anything like a `trim_in_place` method for `String`, so the way you have done it is probably the only way.